# Know Your Site Monday: Who were the first to gold?

Tags: discussion, trivia

Welcome to 'Know Your Site', an every Monday Worldbuilding trivia feature where I use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer and maybe some python parsing to find out interesting things about the site.

I will post a question on Monday, and people have until Thursday at noon to guess the answer! To be clear, using the Data Explorer to get the answer is cheating. If you use that to find the answer, feel good about your inherent superiority, but don't post it! Also, absolutely do not look at my Data Explorer profile, because that is definitely cheating.

**New rule: if you had the accepted answer last week, you can't answer this week. Yes that is you, Secespitus.**

There are 930 people awarded a [gold badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold) as of Sunday, January 28th.

- **Who was the first person to get two gold badges?**
- **Who was the first person to get three gold badges?**
- **Who was the first person to get both a question and answer badge (as defined in the gold badges link above)?**
- **Who was the first person to get two moderation badges?**

Comment: But, but, but...!!

Comment: @Secespitus Look! You were just lurking! I had to take some action!

Comment: I wanted to beat my record from last week...

Comment: @Secespitus How about, you an answer on Wednesday. I honestly don't know if anyone else is even going to look these things up...

Comment: I am sure someone will answer.

Comment: +1 for that sweet sweet note

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Who was the first person to get two gold badges?**
 [overactor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/328/overactor), on Oct 29 '14, both on the same day.

**Who was the first person to get three gold badges?**
Tim B, Jan 16, 2015

**Who was the first person to get both a question and answer badge (as defined in the gold badges link above)?**
[dsollen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4857/dsollen)
Q: Sep 23 '15
A: Oct 9 '15

**Who was the first person to get two moderation badges?**
Looks like HDE 226868♦

Comment: A great showing! The first person to two badges is not correct though; Tim B was second...

Comment: @kingledion Oh crap! It was [overactor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/328/overactor) on Oct 29 '14. I even saw that when I was researching the question and answer badge. I just forgot to fix it! Am I allowed to change my answer? He got two golds on the same day even.

Comment: Yes you are. He got the first two gold medals on the whole site, even! Good job, I really thought that dsollen would be very hard to get.

Comment: @kingledion dsollen was kinda hard to get except I figured out a strategy. If I'm correct, Tim B was also second to get both Q and A, Dec 17 '15 and Nov 6 '14, and so I only had to look at people who got gold before Dec 17. And it's surprising how many people only have the question badges or only have the answer badges, which meant I only had to do a fast glance at most of them.